# How fast does $a_n:=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \frac{dx}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+x^2\right)^{n+1/2}}$ decay as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let
\begin{equation}
a_n:=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \frac{dx}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+x^2\right)^{n+1/2}}
\end{equation}
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, $a_n$ is clearly a monotone decreasing sequence of positive numbers and by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $a_n \to 0^+$ as $n \to \infty$.

However, I have some difficulty estimating how fast $a_n$ decays. For example, $\frac{a_n}{f(n)}=O(1)$ as $n \to \infty$ for some polynomial $f$?

Could anyone please provide insight into the decay rate of $a_n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also try to find the asymptotics of the integral directly.
Making the substitution $x=\frac{t}{\sqrt2}$
$$a_n=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \frac{dx}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+x^2\right)^{n+1/2}}=2^n\int_1^\sqrt2\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{n+1/2}}=2^n\int_1^\sqrt2\frac{e^{-n\ln(1+t^2)}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$
Making one more substitution $t=1+x$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}-1} \frac{e^{-n\ln(1+x+x^2/2)}}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2/2}}dx$$
It is straightforward to see that the function $f(x)=\ln(1+x+x^2/2)$ does not have an extremum on the interval $[0;\sqrt2-1]$, but has the minimal value at $x=0$. Decomposing the integrand near this point
$$\ln(1+x+x^2/2)=f(0)+f'(0)\,x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+...=x+O(x^3)$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2/2}}=1-\frac{1}{2}\,x+O(x^2)$$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\sqrt2-1}e^{-nx}\Big(1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)\Big)dx$$
With the accuracy up to exponentially small corrections we can extend the interval of integration till $\infty$. Performing integration,
$$\boxed{\,\,a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{1}{n}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2n}+O\big(1/n^2\big)\Big)\,\,}$$
Numerical check confirms the asymptotics:

$$n=10\quad a_n=0.0667968\quad \text{approximation}=\frac{1}{10\sqrt2}(1-1/20)=0.067175$$
$$n=30\quad a_n=0.0232066\quad \text{approximation}=\frac{1}{30\sqrt2}(1-1/60)=0.023177$$
$$n=100\quad a_n=0.0070366\quad \text{approximation}=\frac{1}{100\sqrt2}(1-1/200)= 0.00703571$$
$$n=1000\quad a_n=0.000706754\quad \text{approximation}=\frac{1}{1000\sqrt2}(1-1/2000)= 0.000706753$$

Comment: OK, I wonder why your leading coefficient, which is $1/\sqrt{2}$ is different from the previous answer's $\log 2$.

Comment: The leading coefficient in my answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. It is straightforward to check, for example, using WolframAlpha, which formula - $\frac{1}{n\sqrt2}$ or $\frac{\log2}{n}$ - gives a better approximation for bigger $n$ : $n=100; 1000; 10000$, etc.

Comment: @Keith Svyatoslav is correct. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for the high evaluation of my modest result. Of course, this is only your right to choose which solution you like more. But, IMHO, the best and the most elaborated one (which provides a general answer - a full asymptotics) is by @Gary

Comment: This is a nice solution !

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more elementary answer to close the debate. By the change of variable $t = n\,(x^2-1/2)$ (which gives $x^2 + 1/2 = 1+t/n$) one gets
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}^1 \frac{\mathrm d x}{\left(\tfrac{1}{2}+x^2\right)^{n+1/2}} = \frac{1}{2n}\int_0^\frac{n}{2} \frac{\mathrm d t}{\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{1/2}} = \frac{I_n}{2n}
$$
where $I_n = \int_0^\infty f_n$ with
$$
f_n(t) = \frac{\mathbb{1}_{[0,n]}(t)}{\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{1/2}} \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{e^t \left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1/2}}
$$
since $(1+t/n)^n \to e^t$. Hence, by dominated convergence,
$$
I_n = \int_0^\infty f_n \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\int_0^\infty \sqrt{2} \,e^{-t}\,\mathrm d t = \sqrt 2
$$
that is $I_n = \sqrt{2} + o(1)$. Thus,
$$
\int_{1/\sqrt 2}^1 \frac{\mathrm d x}{(\tfrac{1}{2}+x^2)^{n+1/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$
In particular, this agrees with the coefficient given by Svyatoslav.

Comment: Nice usage of the dominated convergence theorem and the integrand transformation!

Answer (score 4):

If we perform the substitution $t = \sqrt {{\rm 2e}^s  - 1}$ in Svyatoslav's formula
$$
a_n  = 2^n \int_1^{\sqrt 2 } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\log (1 + t^2 )} }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^2 } }}{\rm d}t} ,
$$
we obtain
$$
a_n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\int_0^{\log (3/2)} {{\rm e}^{ - ns} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{\sqrt {2 - {\rm e}^{ - s} } }}} .
$$
Now
$$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2 - {\rm e}^{ - s} } }} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {c_k \frac{{s^k }}{{k!}}} 
$$
for $|s|<\log 2$, where
$$\boxed{
c_k  = ( - 1)^k \sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {\frac{{(2j - 1)!!}}{{2^j }}S(k,j)} .}
$$
Here $j!!$ is the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and $S(k,j)$ denotes the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8.i) (cf. [$\mathrm{A}352117$](https://oeis.org/A352117)). Thus, by [Watson's lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.ii),
$$\boxed{
a_n  \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 n}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_k }}{{n^k }}}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 n}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{5}{{4n^2 }} - \frac{{37}}{{8n^3 }} + \frac{{377}}{{16n^4 }} -  \ldots } \right)}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. Note that, in fact,
$$
a_n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 n}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  { P (k + 1,n\log (3/2))\frac{c_k}{{n^k }}} 
$$
where $P(a,z)$ is the [normalised incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.i).

Comment: I was wondering whether and how a full asymptotics can be obtained. Fascinating!

Comment: This is splendid ! I knew the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02827 and I wondered if there are extensions of it for a large negative second argument. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Alternative solution*:

With the substitution $x = \sqrt y$, we have
$$a_n = \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{1}{(1/2 + y)^{n+1/2}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}\,\mathrm{d}y.$$

It is easy to prove that, for all $y \in [1/2, 1]$,
$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(y - 1/2) \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt y} \le \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}.$$

We have
$$\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}{(1/2 + y)^{n+1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}y - \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(y - 1/2)}{(1/2 + y)^{n+1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}y \le a_n \le \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}{(1/2 + y)^{n+1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}y$$
which results in
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{\sqrt 2}{2n-1} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2n-1}(2/3)^{n-1/2} - \frac{2\sqrt 2}{4n^2 - 8n + 3} + \frac{(n + 3/2)\sqrt 2}{4n^2 - 8n + 3}(2/3)^{n-1/2}\\ 
 \le{}& a_n \le \frac{\sqrt 2}{2n-1} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2n-1}(2/3)^{n-1/2}.
\end{align*}

Thus,
$$a_n = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+\frac 12}}=2^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,\, x \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-2 x^2\right)$$
$$a_n=2^n \left(\sqrt{2} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-2\right)-\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-1\right)\right)$$

For large $n$ (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.8))

$$a_n \sim \frac {\log(2)} n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\qquad \qquad \color{red}{\text{wrong !!}}$$ seems to be a decent asymptotics
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation}& \text{solution} \\
 10 & 0.0693147 & 0.0667968 \\
 15 & 0.0462098 & 0.0456901 \\
 20 & 0.0346574 & 0.0345564 \\
 25 & 0.0277259 & 0.0277672 \\
 30 & 0.0231049 & 0.0232066 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

You could also use
$$\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+\frac 12}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} \binom{-\frac{2n+1}{2}}{k} x^{-(2 k+2 n+1)}$$ Integrating termwise and summing
$$\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+\frac 12}}=-\frac{x^{-2 n}}{2 n}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(n,n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;-\frac{1}{2 x^2}\right)$$giving by the end
$$\frac 1{2n} \left(2^n \, _2F_1\left(n,n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;-1\right)-\,
   _2F_1\left(n,n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ which is bit easier to analyse since the first three arguments go to infinity at the same speed.

This form is better from a numerical point of view (very stable).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{value} \\
 10   & 0.0667968393416 \\
 100  & 0.0070365652179 \\
 1000 & 0.0007067541084 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which shows that I misinterpreted something somewhere.

**Update**

If we let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh (t)$
$$I_n=\int_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}^1\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+\frac 12}}=2^n \int_{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right) }^{\sinh ^{-1}(1) }\cosh ^{-2 n}(t)\,dt$$

Using the incomplete beta function in place of the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I_n=2^{n-1} \left(B_3\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)-B_2\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\,i$$ and, now, the correct asymptotics given by @Svyatoslav and extended by @Gary.

Notice that @Gary's formula leads to a relative error smaller than $0.1$% as soon as $n \geq 17$ and smaller than $0.01$% as soon as $n \geq 23$

Comment: Nice solution. I used a different approach )

Comment: It seems there are some corrections to do here ...

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your asymptotics is incorrect. See the other answers.